# ORACLE, PLSQL, Select from pre-populated set of values in WHERE IN clause

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, set, where-in

**Condensed Example & Explanation**

I want to write a WHERE IN clause that selects from a pre-populated set of numbers

Here's some code. I want to store this set of numbers, and select from them so i don't have to repeat the query that generates this set of numbers.

```
ARRAY_OF_NUMBERS = Values from some select statement


  -- SHIPMENTS CURSOR
  OPEN O_SHIPMENTS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_SHIPMENT_INFO SI
        WHERE INTERNAL_ASN IN (ARRAY_OF_NUMBERS) -- need to populate something
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;

  -- ORDER CURSOR
  OPEN O_ORDERS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_ORDER_INFO OI
        WHERE INTERNAL_ASN IN (ARRAY_OF_NUMBERS) -- need to populate something
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;
```

I read something about using an array, but it said it had to be a global array instead of session level. I'm not sure how true this is, and I'm not sure what a global array even is, but i imagine this needs to be session level as it would change with each procedural call. Perhaps i could use a temporary table.

Any ideas on the best way i can accomplish this?

------------- EDIT ------------
(Adding detailed example)

**Detailed Example and Explanation**

I have 4 tables at 4 different hierarchical levels, and 4 stored procedures. Each procedure contains input criteria to build a selection of data at all 4 levels via criteria for a certain level.

In this example, my caller will input selection criteria that exists at the carton level. Then i will use the INTERNAL_ASN numbers narrowed from this selection, to move up hierarchical levels and retrieve: ORDERS this carton is on, SHIPMENTS that ORDER is on, and then down to retrieve: ITEMS on this CARTON.

I noticed when going up levels, i was repeating the same selection, and though i should somehow store this set of numbers, so i didn't rerun the selection each time to get them, but wasn't sure how.

```
      -- SHIPMENTS CURSOR
  OPEN O_SHIPMENTS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_SHIPMENT_INFO SI
        WHERE     INTERNAL_ASN IN
                     (SELECT INTERNAL_ASN
                        FROM Q194977.AN_CARTON_INFO CI
                       WHERE     (I_BOL IS NULL OR BILL_OF_LADING = I_BOL)
                             AND (   I_CARTON_NO IS NULL
                                  OR CARTON_NO = I_CARTON_NO)
                             AND (I_PO_NO = 0 OR PO_NO = I_PO_NO)
                             AND (I_STORE_NO = 0 OR STORE_NO = I_STORE_NO))
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;

  -- ORDER CURSOR
  OPEN O_ORDERS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_ORDER_INFO OI
        WHERE     INTERNAL_ASN IN
                     (SELECT INTERNAL_ASN
                        FROM Q194977.AN_CARTON_INFO CI
                       WHERE     (I_BOL IS NULL OR BILL_OF_LADING = I_BOL)
                             AND (   I_CARTON_NO IS NULL
                                  OR CARTON_NO = I_CARTON_NO)
                             AND (I_PO_NO = 0 OR PO_NO = I_PO_NO)
                             AND (I_STORE_NO = 0 OR STORE_NO = I_STORE_NO))
              AND (I_PO_NO = 0 OR PO_NO = I_PO_NO)
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;

  -- CARTONS CURSOR
  OPEN O_CARTONS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_CARTON_INFO CI
        WHERE     (I_BOL IS NULL OR BILL_OF_LADING = I_BOL)
              AND (I_CARTON_NO IS NULL OR CARTON_NO = I_CARTON_NO)
              AND (I_PO_NO = 0 OR PO_NO = I_PO_NO)
              AND (I_STORE_NO = 0 OR STORE_NO = I_STORE_NO)
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;

  -- ITEMS CURSOR
  OPEN O_ITEMS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_ITEM_INFO II
        WHERE     CARTON_NO IN
                     (SELECT CARTON_NO
                        FROM Q194977.AN_CARTON_INFO CI
                       WHERE     (I_BOL IS NULL OR BILL_OF_LADING = I_BOL)
                             AND (   I_CARTON_NO IS NULL
                                  OR CARTON_NO = I_CARTON_NO)
                             AND (I_PO_NO = 0 OR PO_NO = I_PO_NO)
                             AND (I_STORE_NO = 0 OR STORE_NO = I_STORE_NO))
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;
```

Comment: Not sure if this is mostly a terminology issue. It sounds like you want a schema- or databse-level array type, which means something created in SQL with `create type` rather than declared in PL/SQL. Then you can use a `table()` call instead of the `in`. Is that what you mean? [Something like this, maybe?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17039852/266304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean a collection of numbers (there are three collection types in PL/SQL, one of which is an associative array, but that doesn't sound like what you want here), you could do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_tbl
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Then, in your procedure

```
  l_nums num_tbl;
BEGIN
  SELECT some_number
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_nums
    FROM <<your query to get the numbers>>;

  <<more code>>

  OPEN O_SHIPMENTS_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT *
         FROM Q194977.AN_SHIPMENT_INFO SI
        WHERE INTERNAL_ASN IN (SELECT column_value
                                 FROM TABLE( l_nums )) 
     ORDER BY INTERNAL_ASN;
```

That is syntactically valid.  Whether it is actually going to be useful to you, however, is a separate question.

- Collections are stored in the relatively expensive PGA memory on the database server.  If you're storing a couple hundred numbers in a collection, that's probably not a huge concern.  If, on the other hand, you're storing 10's or 100's of MB of data and running this in multiple sessions, this one bit of code could easily consume many GB of the RAM on the database server leading to lots of performance issues.
- Moving large quantities of data from SQL to PL/SQL and then back to SQL can also be somewhat problematic from a performance standpoint-- it's generally more efficient to leave everything in SQL and let the SQL engine handle it.
- If you use a collection in this way, you're preventing the optimizer from considering join orders and query plans that merge the two queries in a more efficient manner.  If you are certain that the most efficient plan is one where a small number of `internal_asn` values are used to probe the `an_shipment_info` table using an index, that may not be a major concern.  If you're not sure about what the best query plan is, and particularly if your actual queries are more complicated than what you posted, however, you might be preventing the optimizer from using the most efficient plan for each query.

What is the problem that you're trying to solve?  You talk about not wanting to duplicate code.  That would lead me to suspect that you really just want a view that you can reference in your queries rather than repeating the code for a complicated SQL statement.  But that presumes that the issue you're trying to solve is one of code elegance which may or may not be accurate.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had more detail at first, and deleted it thinking i was over complicating my question. I edited and added it back at the bottom. In this code example, i'm coming in with criteria to narrow results via the CARTON level, and then repeating the query to get INTERNAL_ASN numbers to move up and get the other levels. Coming from Software Engineering background, i always figure duplicate code is bad, but maybe keeping this in SQL is better like you were saying. I'm not sure. This selection changes each time via whats entered, and what lvl, so i don't see a view working.

Comment: Oh, and this is likely a set of 1-100 numbers, so i don't think memory should be a problem.