# PL SQL: How to populate a cursor in loop

Tags: oracle11g

I have a scenario to implement where in we will have an SP with two parameters 
1) In parameter of array of Varchar2
2) Cursor -- Out parameter

We have populate the cursor only for each Value passed in array and this opened/populated cursor will be used by Java. But what i have found till now is, if we have to process an array then it should have to be done using loop.

For ex:

```
Open Cursor_Name
For 
For index In Arrar_Parameter.FIRST .. Arrar_Parameter.LAST
LOOP
    SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EmpId = Arrar_Parameter[i] -------> This needs to be looped and not sure if this will work
END LOOP
```

Can we have some thing like this

```
Open Cursor_Name
For 
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EmpId IN (Arrar_Parameter values) ------> To fetch/put all the array values at once without loop.
```

Kindly suggest hot to populate cursor in this scenario

Comment: What data type is the 'array'?

Comment: @AlexPoole Array will be of Varchar2(30) type

Comment: You said it's an array though; so is it a `varray` or a nested table? Well, I've covered both in my answer hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array parameter is a schema-level `varray` or nested table, you can use [a table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30047):

> The table_collection_expression lets you inform Oracle that the value of collection_expression should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations. The collection_expression can be a subquery, a column, a function, or a collection constructor. Regardless of its form, it must return a collection value—that is, a value whose type is nested table or varray. This process of extracting the elements of a collection is called collection unnesting.

This uses a built-in `varray` type but you can substitute your own:

```
create procedure procedure_name (
  array_parameter sys.odcivarchar2list, cursor_name out sys_refcursor
) as
begin
  open cursor_name for
    select e.*
    from table (array_parameter) a
    join emp e on e.empid = a.column_value;
end;
/
```

You can also use `in` if you prefer:

```
create procedure procedure_name (
  array_parameter sys.odcivarchar2list, cursor_name out sys_refcursor
) as
begin
  open cursor_name for
    select *
    from emp
    where empid in (select column_value from table (array_parameter));
end;
/
```

If it is a nested table you can also use the `member of` syntax:

```
create type my_varchar2_table as table of varchar2(30);
/

create procedure procedure_name (
  array_parameter my_varchar2_table, cursor_name out sys_refcursor
) as
begin
  open cursor_name for
    select *
    from emp
    where empid member of array_parameter;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Alex Poole, just need one more suggestion....if we create this array of VARCHAR2 in db and when JAVA application calls this SP with an array of string in JAVA, so this implementation of SP will work?Kindly suggest

Comment: @PS078 - I'm not quite sure what you mean; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034016/266304) shows how to convert a Java array to a `varray` collection. It's for numbers but it works the same way for strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex Poole. I shall try implementing your suggestions and ask you know in case find any problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @Alex Poole, Kindly suggest here, I am getting error(PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR) while populating Ref_cursor, the code is like this

        OPEN Ref_cur_Price details 
        FOR
        SELECT  *  FROM VW_PRODUCTS_PRICES WHERE ORIG_Id MEMBER OF Nested_Table_ids;

VW_PRODUCTS_PRICES is a View 
Nested_Table_ids is a table of Varchar2(100)
One more point. ORIG_Id column of view is of NVARCHAR(200) type, can this data type mismatch also throw error.

Comment: They need to be the same type, I'm not sure if it will allow implicit conversion between varchar2 and nvarchar2 though. Have you declared the data type for `nested_table_ids` as a PL/SQL type, or at schema level (with `create type ...`)?

Comment: Hello @Alex Poole, I have created the type at Package level like this,   create or replace PACKAGE DATA_PREP_PKG AUTHID DEFINER IS 
   TYPE nested_table_ids IS   TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(200);                      Also i have tried with converting the nested table type as NVARCHAR2(200), but still getting same error.

Comment: Error is: PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR

Comment: [The type *has* to be declared at schema level](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17039852/266304) for you to use it in an SQL query. The built-in type I used in my example is defined as an SQL type, not a PL/SQL type.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex Poole, it worked after creating the Type at schema level

Comment: Hello @Alex Poole, I am willing to learn PLSQL collections concepts in depth and for this I request you to please suggest any source/tutorial to start from scratch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PS078 - recommendations are off-topic. But [start with the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005).

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole